# Angular UI-Grid filtering by strict match

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm creating a table with Angular UI-Grid and I wanted to filter the table contents by a strict match. By default "Car" input will match with "Carol" but I want UI-Grid's filtering to only match if the input is equal to a table entry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
{
        field: 'email',
        filter: {
          condition: uiGridConstants.filter.EXACT,
          placeholder: 'your email'
        } 
      }
```

Comment: Thank you, that filter type is not present in the uiGrid api documentation page

Comment: Does someone know how to filter EXACT if there is a uiGridConstants.filter.SELECT ?

Answer (score 2):

Trying uiGridConstants.filter.EXACT causes fetching also CAR 1, CAR 2.

If you want to fetch "CAR" only, excluding "CAR 1" and "CAR 2", using a function would be useful:

```
{ field: 'name', width :'150', filter: {
        condition: function(searchTerm, cellValue) {
            if (searchTerm === cellValue)
               return -1;
            else 
               return 0;             
          }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a filter method. Instead of having `ng-repeat="x in items|filter:filterVariable"` use a filter method. In your controller code put:

```
var myFilter = function(x){
  return x == $scope.filterVariable;
}
```

and the `ng-repeat` would look like:

```
ng-repeat="x in items | filter:myFilter"
```